# Changing div value dynamically, navigation bar on laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, navigation, laravel-blade

I'm currently using laravel blade and i currently implemented bootstrap along with the blade template.

Would want to have the navigation button able to interact dynamically along with the selected pages

```
<div class="navbar">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><b>iMakan</b></a>
           </div>
    <div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a class="active "href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="auth/login">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="503">Cart</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "interact dynamically along with the selected pages"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Laravel provides a built-in function you can use: `Request::is()`.

From the [API docs](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_is):

> Determine if the current request URI matches a pattern.

You use is like this:

```
Request::is('about'); // returns a boolean

<a href="about" @if(Request::is('about')) class="active" @endif>
```

You could write a helper function to take care of it:

```
function isActive($path, $class = 'active')
{
    return (Request::is($path)) ? $class : '';
}
```

Put it in a file called `helpers.php` in your `app` directory and include it in the autoload-part of your `composer.json` like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

Maybe you need to do a `composer dump-autoload` in your terminal.

---

And finally use it like this:

```
<a href="about" class="{{ isActive('about') }}">About</a>
```

Comment: That's great! Please don't forget to mark an answer as "accepted" if it helped you solve your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my way What i do, You shall follow this too

If you have the last part of url like `home` for Home, `aboutus` for About Us, then you can do this

**Step 1 :**

Get Request Uri

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

**Step 2 :**

Inside you `class` you can have this condition

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/') { echo 'active'; } ?>
```

So you will be having

```
<li><a href="about" class='<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/') { echo 'active'; } ?>' >About Us</a></li>
```

The condition will echo `active` according to your uri

So you will be having something this

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a class="<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/') { echo 'active'; } ?>" href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class='<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/aboutus') { echo 'active'; } ?>'href="about" >About Us</a></li>
    <li><a class='<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/contactus') { echo 'active'; } ?>'href="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a class='<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/login') { echo 'active'; } ?>' href="auth/login">Login</a></li>
    <li><a class='<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/cart') { echo 'active'; } ?>' href="503">Cart</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Then you will be getting the `class='active'` according to your url.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [package](https://github.com/letrunghieu/active) you can use, but using only what laravel provides I would suggest the following:

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('home') }}" 
   class="{{ Route::current()->getName() === 'home' ? : 'active' : ''">Home</a>
```

Using `URL::route(...)` will create a URL based on the name of the route and you can check if this name is currently used with the providec check. To name a route, read the [laravel documentation about routing.](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#named-routes)